# What causes a WHERE clause to be ignored in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've run into this issue before and never really figured out what the issue was. I'm hoping one of you gurus out there to help explain what can cause a WHERE clause to be ignored.The big picture questions are:

**When WHERE clauses are being ignored, where's the best place to start looking?**

**What commonly causes this problem?**

In this specific case, I'm trying to filter out certain service codes. I've tried using NOT LIKE clauses, or just whitelisting the service codes I want using an IN () clause but the statement is completely ignored either way. Each service code is also associated with a service class, and using these same operators to filter out or whitelist the desired service classes does nothing. I've tried moving the NOT LIKE and IN clauses to be the first criteria under my WHERE in the event it's an order of operations issue and I've triple checked for missing parenthesis somewhere. So, this query is returning results without any error messages, but it's not filtering out undesired rows.

The query is a mess because each invoice has 5 different fields that a TechID can be in, each field signifying something different, but here's the query:

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT
            "LocationCode"
        FROM
            "Locations"
        WHERE
            "Invoices"."LocationID" = "Locations"."LocationID"
    ) AS "Location",
    "Invoices"."OrderNum",
    "Invoices"."ServiceCode",
    "Invoices"."WorkDate",
    "Invoices"."Total",
--  "Classes"."Code" AS "ServiceClass",
    (
        SELECT
            "Employees"."Username"
        FROM
            "Employees"
        WHERE
            "Employees"."TechId" = "Invoices"."TechID1"
    ) AS 'Tech',
    (
        SELECT
            "Employees"."Username"
        FROM
            "Employees"
        WHERE
            "Employees"."TechId" = "Invoices"."TechID2"
    ) AS 'Helper',
    (
        SELECT
            "Employees"."Username"
        FROM
            "Employees"
        WHERE
            "Employees"."TechId" = "Invoices"."TechID3"
    ) AS 'Sales Blue 1',
    (
        SELECT
            "Employees"."Username"
        FROM
            "Employees"
        WHERE
            "Employees"."TechId" = "Invoices"."TechID4"
    ) AS 'Sales Blue 2',
    (
        SELECT
            "Employees"."Username"
        FROM
            "Employees"
        WHERE
            "Employees"."TechId" = "Invoices"."TechID5"
    ) AS 'Term Self',
    CASE
WHEN --Self Gen
"Invoices"."TechID5" IN (
    '298',
    '194',
    '330',
    '391',
    '335'
) THEN
    (
        SELECT
            "Employees"."Username"
        FROM
            "Employees"
        WHERE
            "Employees"."TechId" = "Invoices"."TechID5"
    )
WHEN --Sales Blue 2
"Invoices"."TechID4" IN (
    '298',
    '194',
    '330',
    '391',
    '335'
) THEN
    (
        SELECT
            "Employees"."Username"
        FROM
            "Employees"
        WHERE
            "Employees"."TechId" = "Invoices"."TechID4"
    )
WHEN --Sales Blue 1
"Invoices"."TechID3" IN (
    '298',
    '194',
    '330',
    '391',
    '335'
) THEN
    (
        SELECT
            "Employees"."Username"
        FROM
            "Employees"
        WHERE
            "Employees"."TechId" = "Invoices"."TechID3"
    )
END AS "Sales Rep",
 CASE
WHEN --Self Gen
"Invoices"."TechID5" IN (
    '298',
    '194',
    '330',
    '391',
    '335'
) THEN
    'Self-Gen'
WHEN --Sales Blue 2
"Invoices"."TechID4" IN (
    '298',
    '194',
    '330',
    '391',
    '335'
) THEN
    'BSP Lead 2'
WHEN --Sales Blue 1
"Invoices"."TechID3" IN (
    '298',
    '194',
    '330',
    '391',
    '335'
) THEN
    'BSP Lead'
ELSE
    'Error'
END AS "Sale Status"
FROM

    (
        (
            "Employees" "Employees"
            INNER JOIN "Invoices" "Invoices" ON "Employees"."TechID" = "Invoices"."TechID3"
        )
        INNER JOIN "Services" "Services" ON "Invoices"."ServiceCode" = "Services"."Code"
    )
INNER JOIN "Classes" "Classes" ON "Services"."ClassID" = "Classes"."ClassID"
WHERE
    -- Brian is 298, Cindy is 194, Jeremiah is 330, Monty is 391, and Tom is 335.
    -- Technician AND Sales Rep
    "Invoices"."ServiceCode" IN (
        'BED BUG CHEM CO',
        'BED BUG CHEM'
    )
AND (
    "Invoices"."TechID1" IN (
        '298',
        '194',
        '330',
        '391',
        '335'
    )
    AND "Invoices"."TechID3" IN (
        '298',
        '194',
        '330',
        '391',
        '335'
    )
    OR "Invoices"."TechID5" IN (
        '298',
        '194',
        '330',
        '391',
        '335'
    )
)
OR -- Sales Blue 1, Sold but BSPC Lead
"Invoices"."TechID3" IN (
    '298',
    '194',
    '330',
    '391',
    '335'
)
OR --Sales Blue 2
"Invoices"."TechID4" IN (
    '298',
    '194',
    '330',
    '391',
    '335'
)
OR --Term Self (Gen)
"Invoices"."TechID5" IN (
    '298',
    '194',
    '330',
    '391',
    '335'
)
AND (
    "Invoices"."WorkDate" <= GetDate()
    AND YEAR ("Invoices"."WorkDate") = YEAR (GetDate())
)
    AND "Invoices"."ServiceCode" NOT LIKE 'EOM%'
    AND "Invoices"."ServiceCode" NOT LIKE 'EOM1%'
    AND "Invoices"."ServiceCode" NOT LIKE 'M_%'
    AND "Invoices"."ServiceCode" NOT LIKE 'M1%'
    AND "Invoices"."ServiceCode" NOT LIKE 'Q_%'
    AND "Invoices"."ServiceCode" NOT LIKE 'Q1__%'
/*
AND "Classes"."Code" NOT IN ('EOM', 'QUARTERLY', 'MONTHLY')
*/
ORDER BY
    "Sales Rep",
    "Sale Status"
```

Any advice or counsel would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like another case of someone mixing `OR` and `AND` without being *very* careful about parentheses.

Comment: Why you have all fields and tables inside double-quote?

Comment: Are the TechIDX fields strings or numbers? You're encasing them in single quotes which denotes that they're strings.

Comment: I'm using Navicat and that's how it formats it whenever you use the 'Beautify SQL' feature. Not sure why it does it either, but it works.

Comment: @FLICKER: SQL allows for double quotes instead of square brackets. So `"Invoices" ` is the same as `[Invoices]`.

Comment: This is not how you do whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: Now the question is: Why adding bracket for all fields and tables? It's just unnecessary and makes the query busy.

Comment: **FLICKER** I'm using Navicat and that's how it formats it whenever you use the 'Beautify SQL' feature. Not sure why it does it either, but it works.

**Russell Fox** The techIDx fields are numbers. I went ahead and just used the TechID's for the 5 employees rather than having the same lookup subquery repeated dozens of times.

Comment: I suggest you remove the where clauses and add them one by one. This way you can get close to the issue. Also, I see you have mixed AND and ORs (before the last ORDER BY) w/o having parentheses. Review your query and possibly you'll find it.

Comment: If you have any control over design at all, this is a very poor database design and is not normalized at all. It will always be inefficient to query, a pain to write queries for  and is likely to have many data problems. It woudl be best if you redesign to properly normalized tables.

Comment: @HLGEM I don't have any control over the DB. This is actually a software suite we use and they generally discourage users from going into the underlying DB as I am. They've even taken steps to make it harder to use outside of their software. Only problem is their reporting functionality is something you'd expect to find in Windows 95 era software.

Comment: COTS (Commerical Off The Shelf) products often have the worst database designs in my experience. I have never had to work with one yet that was well designed and I have had to go into the guts of hundreds of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no situation that would lead to an entire where clause being ignored. What's probably happening is that your where clause has expressions on either side of an OR, and if one side evaluates to true then the other side doesn't matter. You have to be very careful with your parenthesis when you're combining lots of ANDs and ORs like this.

Comment: There is no case when a where clause is ignored? I would doubt that `WHERE MyColumn IS NULL OR MyColumn IS NOT NULL` would not be killed by the query optimizer.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll run through my parenthesis again looking for errors. To **Sefe**'s point, I'm new to SQL and don't have much understanding about how things are processed. That's what spurred the question.

Comment: @gordy was right. The parenthesis I had were correctly placed and paired, it turned out that I just needed one more set for the proper order of operations. I'd upvote you and your answer but I'm still too much of a n00b.

Comment: @Sefe optimized away sure, but not ignored - if the table didn't have a MyColumn column for example you'd get a syntax error

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reformat of your query, I've marked where I think your `or`s are out of order.

```
select 
  Location = (select LocationCode 
              from Locations 
              where Invoices.Locationid = Locations.Locationid)
 , Invoices.OrderNum
 , Invoices.ServiceCode
 , Invoices.WorkDate
 , Invoices.Total
 /* , ServiceClass = Classes.Code */
 , Tech   = (select Employees.Username 
             from Employees 
             where Employees.TechId = Invoices.Techid1)
 , Helper = (select Employees.Username
             from Employees
             where Employees.TechId = Invoices.Techid2)
 , 'Sales Blue 1' = (select Employees.Username
                     from Employees
                     where Employees.TechId = Invoices.Techid3)
 , 'Sales Blue 2' = (select Employees.Username
                     from Employees
                     where Employees.TechId = Invoices.Techid4)
 , 'Term Self'    = (select Employees.Username
                     from Employees
                     where Employees.TechId = Invoices.Techid5)
 , 'Sales Rep' = case 
   when /* self Gen */ Invoices.Techid5 in ('298', '194', '330', '391', '335') 
     then (
       select Employees.Username
       from Employees
       where Employees.TechId = Invoices.Techid5) 
   when /* Sales Blue 2 */ Invoices.Techid4 in ('298', '194', '330', '391', '335') 
    then (
      select Employees.Username
      from Employees
      where Employees.TechId = Invoices.Techid4) 
   when /* Sales Blue 1 */ Invoices.Techid3 in ('298', '194', '330', '391', '335') 
    then (
      select Employees.Username
      from Employees
      where Employees.TechId = Invoices.Techid3) 
   end 
 , Sale status = case 
      when /* self Gen */ Invoices.Techid5 in ('298', '194', '330', '391', '335') 
        then 'Self-Gen' 
      when /* Sales Blue 2 */ Invoices.Techid4 in ('298', '194', '330', '391', '335') 
        then 'bsp Lead 2' 
      when /* Sales Blue 1 */ Invoices.Techid3 in ('298', '194', '330', '391', '335') 
        then 'bsp Lead' 
        else 'Error' 
        end
from Employees Employees 
  inner join Invoices Invoices on Employees.Techid = Invoices.Techid3
  inner join Services Services on Invoices.ServiceCode = Services.Code
  inner join Classes Classes on Services.Classid = Classes.Classid
where /* Brian is 298, Cindy is 194, Jeremiah is 330, Monty is 391, and Tom is 335. */ 
 /* Technician and Sales Rep */ 
  Invoices.ServiceCode in ('bed bug chem co', 'bed bug chem')
  and (
        Invoices.Techid1 in ('298', '194', '330', '391', '335')
    and Invoices.Techid3 in ('298', '194', '330', '391', '335')
     or Invoices.Techid5 in ('298', '194', '330', '391', '335')  
    )   /* Sales Blue 1 , Sold but bspc Lead */ 

/* ----------------------------------------------- */    
/* do these 'or's belong somewhere else? */
  or Invoices.Techid3 in ('298', '194', '330', '391', '335')   /* Sales Blue 2 */ 
  or Invoices.Techid4 in ('298', '194', '330', '391', '335')    /* Term self (Gen) */ 
  or Invoices.Techid5 in ('298', '194', '330', '391', '335')
/* ----------------------------------------------- */
  and (
      Invoices.WorkDate <= GetDate()
        and year(Invoices.WorkDate) = year(GetDate())
    )
  and Invoices.ServiceCode not like 'eom%'
  and Invoices.ServiceCode not like 'eom1%'
  and Invoices.ServiceCode not like 'M_%'
  and Invoices.ServiceCode not like 'M1%'
  and Invoices.ServiceCode not like 'Q_%'
  and Invoices.ServiceCode not like 'Q1__%'
/* and Classes.Code not in ('eom', 'quarterly', 'monthly') */
order by Sales Rep, Sale status
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    Locations.LocationCode AS [Location],
    Invoices.OrderNum,
    Invoices.ServiceCode,
    Invoices.WorkDate,
    Invoices.Total,
--  Classes.Code AS ServiceClass,
    Tech.Username AS Tech,
    Helper.Username AS Helper,
    SB1.Username AS [Sales Blue 1],
    SB2.Username AS [Sales Blue 2],
    TS.Username AS [Term Self],
    CASE
        WHEN --Self Gen
        Invoices.TechID5 IN (
            298,194,330,391,335) 
        THEN TS.Username
    ELSE 
        CASE WHEN --Sales Blue 2
            Invoices.TechID4 IN (
                298,194,330,391,335) 
            THEN SB2.Username
        ELSE
            CASE WHEN --Sales Blue 1
                Invoices.TechID3 IN (
                    298,194,330,391,335) 
                THEN SB1.Username
            END 
        END
    END
    AS [Sales Rep],
     CASE WHEN --Self Gen
        Invoices.TechID5 IN (
            298,194,330,391,335) 
        THEN 'Self-Gen'
    ELSE
        CASE WHEN --Sales Blue 2
            Invoices.TechID4 IN (
                298,194,330,391,335) 
            THEN 'BSP Lead 2'
        ELSE
            CASE WHEN --Sales Blue 1
                Invoices.TechID3 IN (
                    298,194,330,391,335)
                THEN 'BSP Lead'
                ELSE 'Error'
            END
        END
    END AS [Sale Status]
FROM Employees 
    INNER JOIN Invoices 
        ON Employees.TechID = Invoices.TechID3
    INNER JOIN [Services] 
        ON Invoices.ServiceCode = [Services].Code
    INNER JOIN Classes
        ON [Services].ClassID = Classes.ClassID
    INNER JOIN Locations
        ON Invoices.LocationID = Locations.LocationID
    -- Brian is 298, Cindy is 194, Jeremiah is 330, Monty is 391, and Tom is 335.
    -- Technician AND Sales Rep
    INNER JOIN Employees Tech
        ON Tech.TechID = Invoices.TechID1
    INNER JOIN Employees Helper
        ON Helper.TechID = Invoices.TechID2
    INNER JOIN Employees SB1
        ON SB1.TechID = Invoices.TechID3
    INNER JOIN Employees SB2
        ON SB2.TechID = Invoices.TechID4
    INNER JOIN Employees TS
        ON TS.TechID = Invoices.TechID5
WHERE
    Invoices.ServiceCode IN (
        'BED BUG CHEM CO',
        'BED BUG CHEM'
        )
    AND Invoices.WorkDate <= GetDate()
    AND YEAR (Invoices.WorkDate) = YEAR (GetDate())
    AND Invoices.ServiceCode NOT LIKE 'EOM%'
    AND Invoices.ServiceCode NOT LIKE 'EOM1%'
    AND Invoices.ServiceCode NOT LIKE 'M_%'
    AND Invoices.ServiceCode NOT LIKE 'M1%'
    AND Invoices.ServiceCode NOT LIKE 'Q_%'
    AND Invoices.ServiceCode NOT LIKE 'Q1__%'
    /* AND Classes.Code NOT IN ('EOM', 'QUARTERLY', 'MONTHLY') */
    ORDER BY
        CASE
            WHEN --Self Gen
            Invoices.TechID5 IN (
                298,194,330,391,335) 
            THEN TS.Username
        ELSE 
            CASE WHEN --Sales Blue 2
                Invoices.TechID4 IN (
                    298,194,330,391,335) 
                THEN SB2.Username
            ELSE
                CASE WHEN --Sales Blue 1
                    Invoices.TechID3 IN (
                        298,194,330,391,335) 
                    THEN SB1.Username
                END 
            END
        END,
         CASE WHEN --Self Gen
            Invoices.TechID5 IN (
                298,194,330,391,335) 
            THEN 'Self-Gen'
        ELSE
            CASE WHEN --Sales Blue 2
                Invoices.TechID4 IN (
                    298,194,330,391,335) 
                THEN 'BSP Lead 2'
            ELSE
                CASE WHEN --Sales Blue 1
                    Invoices.TechID3 IN (
                        298,194,330,391,335)
                    THEN 'BSP Lead'
                    ELSE 'Error'
                END
            END
        END ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely the problem is with your order of operations due to not specifically using parentheses properly when using and and Or in the same query. Let me break down a small part of your query and you can see what I mean

```
WHERE
    -- Brian is 298, Cindy is 194, Jeremiah is 330, Monty is 391, and Tom is 335.
    -- Technician AND Sales Rep
    "Invoices"."ServiceCode" IN ( 'BED BUG CHEM CO', 'BED BUG CHEM' )
AND ( "Invoices"."TechID1" IN ( '298', '194', '330'  '391', '335')
    AND "Invoices"."TechID3" IN ( '298', '194', '330'  '391', '335')
    OR "Invoices"."TechID5" IN ( '298', '194', '330'  '391', '335')
)
```

Let's try different ways of arranging the data and see what the different values you would get are:

This variant - you want one of the values to be in both TechID1 and TechID3 (but since it is a list, they don't have to contain the same value (TechID1 = 298 and TechID3 = 194 would work) except when TechID5 contains the values, you don't care what the value is in TechID1 or TechID3 (so in this case if TechID5 = 298, then TechID1 could equal 299 and TechID3 could equal 301)

```
WHERE
-- Brian is 298, Cindy is 194, Jeremiah is 330, Monty is 391, and Tom is 335.
-- Technician AND Sales Rep
"Invoices"."ServiceCode" IN ( 'BED BUG CHEM CO', 'BED BUG CHEM' )
AND ( "Invoices"."TechID1" IN ( '298', '194', '330'  '391', '335')
    AND "Invoices"."TechID3" IN ( '298', '194', '330'  '391', '335'))
    OR "Invoices"."TechID5" IN ( '298', '194', '330'  '391', '335')
)
```

In this variant you care if those tech ids are in any one of three fields

```
    WHERE
    -- Brian is 298, Cindy is 194, Jeremiah is 330, Monty is 391, and Tom is 335.
    -- Technician AND Sales Rep
    "Invoices"."ServiceCode" IN ( 'BED BUG CHEM CO', 'BED BUG CHEM' )
AND ( "Invoices"."TechID1" IN ( '298', '194', '330'  '391', '335')
    OR "Invoices"."TechID3" IN ( '298', '194', '330'  '391', '335')
    OR "Invoices"."TechID5" IN ( '298', '194', '330'  '391', '335')
)
```

In this variant TechID1 must contain one of the values and one of the values can be in either TechID3 or TechID5

```
    WHERE
    -- Brian is 298, Cindy is 194, Jeremiah is 330, Monty is 391, and Tom is 335.
    -- Technician AND Sales Rep
    "Invoices"."ServiceCode" IN ( 'BED BUG CHEM CO', 'BED BUG CHEM' )
AND ( "Invoices"."TechID1" IN ( '298', '194', '330'  '391', '335')
    AND ("Invoices"."TechID3" IN ( '298', '194', '330'  '391', '335')
    OR "Invoices"."TechID5" IN ( '298', '194', '330'  '391', '335'))
)
```

Without knowing your business rules, we can't say which variant is correct. All are working SQL code.

It is a critical practice to use parentheses anytime you intend to mix AND and OR even if the order of operations would give the correct answer because in six months when you need to revise the query, you won't know if this is incorrect or if it was intended. When you use the () every time, then intent is always clear.